# Heroku not pushing Django App due to buildpack error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to upload my Django project to Heroku with Python.

My app was built on Python 3.6.1 and when I go to push the app to heroku I am receiving the following error message in the terminal:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to random-appio.
```

remote:

I have included a runtime.txt file containing the following:

```
python-3.6.1
```

I also have a Procfile containing:

```
web: sh -c "cd directory && gunicorn directory.wsgi"
```

As well as a requirements.txt file containing:

```
Django==2.0.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
pytz==2018.3
whitenoise==3.3.1
```

My requirements.txt, Procfile and runtime.txt are all in the project directory.

I can't see where I am going wrong here - any ideas?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you tried, inside your `Procfile` file, to change to: `web: gunicorn dotted.path.to.project.wsgi`?

Comment: Just tried there - no difference. Same error.

Comment: Have you done `git add requirements.txt Procfile` and `git commit`, before pushing to heroku?

Comment: Yep all added - http://oi63.tinypic.com/dwf43d.jpg

Comment: + directory with it inside - http://oi67.tinypic.com/2a2aza.jpg

Comment: have you tried to do all these from the beginning? If yes, then please share the github repo link to see the structure of your app.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this situation i browsed about 3 hours then i came to know about the silly mistake that my file is named as requirement.txt, it should be requirements.txt
if this not helps, check out the supported python runtime version on heroku site

Answer (score 0):

Veirify that the ".txt" in "requirements.txt" is not duplicated.

When I named the file, I explicitly typed requirements.txt which resulted in a file named

requirements.txt.txt that was not being detected.